# NGINX - URL rewriting

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I can't seem to be able to rewrite the following url :

> https://website.org/urlCNX/Files/software/software.application?CNX=CNX&UUID=66A6DUZS7Z4L742VHZ594ZAPM9P06

to

> https://website.org/url/Files/software/software.application?CNX=CNX&UUID=66A6DUZS7Z4L742VHZ594ZAPM9P06

(Note the missing "CNX" after /url)

I've currently set the following rule in NGINX but it does nothing :

> ```
>    location ~* /iComptaCNX/ {
>        rewrite ^/iCompta/(.+) $1 permanent;
>    }
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/iComptaCNX/(.+)$ /iCompta/$1 permanent;`

Comment: That's it ! Thank you that was what I needed.

Comment: @RichardSmith Hi, as it worked, I suggest to post your comment as a answer, thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression in the `rewrite` statement needs to match the URI you are attempting to change. It needs to match URIs that begin with `/iComptaCNX/...`. Your current attempt will not match that URI.

Try:

```
rewrite ^/iComptaCNX/(.+)$ /iCompta/$1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

---

If you want a general solution that will remove CNX from the end of the first element in any URI, use:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)CNX/(.+)$ /$1/$2 permanent;
```