# how redirect to specific after word with nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works.

A website has switched CMS services, and i want after **?page=** page redirect to main content ! on nginx and with rewrite

I need to redirect all URLs that contain the word "?page=" redirect to parent url

E.g.

```
domain.com/blog/item110?page=2
```

i want redirect to

```
domain.com/blog/item110
```

Another E.g.

```
domain.com/blog/biond?page=2
```

i want redirect to

```
domain.com/blog/biond
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NGINX - URL rewriting](https://serverfault.com/questions/991644/nginx-url-rewriting)

Comment: not my anwer bro my parent url is dynamic ! and i want all url after **?page=** redirect to parent

Comment: It explains how to do rewrites in nginx, showing you the syntax. We are not a nginx rule writing service; we in general expect some effort before asking. The linked question shows you how to to capture of part of the string and reuse that, and the general syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nginx, `?page=` is an argument, which is available in the variable `$arg_page`.

Also, the `$uri` variable contains the current URL with all the arguments removed.

So, one solution is:

```
if ($arg_page != "") { return 301 $uri; }
```

See the [manual page for if](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if).